# Parse or crawl Facebook comments

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, html-parsing

I´d like to use the Facebook Comments plugin for my website.
As Facebook is offering this as an iFrame, the actual comments are not part of my content.
Therefore I am looking for a solution to read the comments and render them into my website.
So far with no luck.
There is an older article, which also links to code that seemed to work.

https://moz.com/blog/make-facebook-comments-box-indexable-by-search-engines

However, changes on the Facebook side seem to have made that code unusable. Has anyone found a new solution for this?
Maybe via curl or file_get_contents or even the official API?

Please note, I am referring to the comments plugin for URLs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/)

not comments from Facebook Pages or Profiles.

Comment: should be a simple html scrape job. got a live url i can check out?

Comment: [Social Plugins FAQ: Can I get comments for a URL via an API?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008)

Comment: Awesome! hanshenrik, thank you. No need for it anymore. CBroe found the right solution! THank you very much!